# Slickgrid memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, slickgrid

I am a novice in javascript.  I am creating slick grid using the below function and I manipulate the url based on date and get data.  When I use this code for different dates, the memory requirement in browser is increasing.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var createSlickGrid = function(data, key) {
    var options = ...;
    new Slick.grid($('#temp'), data, options);
}

getData = function(date) {
    url = <some function based on date>;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       createSlickGrid(data, key);
       data = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to create a new slickgrid each time, but rather use the slick.remotemodel.js that comes in the slickgrid package. Use this example as a reference to get you going: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

When you create the new Slickgrid, you are not clearing out the old, so they keep building until garbage collection eventually gets to it.

Aid your code by returning the instance of Slick.grid, so when you create a new one, if that is what you want, as @Drew was corrected, you could simply reload it, then you can dereference the original Slickgrid, or set it to NULL to allow the garbage collection to clean it up.